# Using sed in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, sed

I'm currently currently editing 100 of files in which I have this certain code

```
:id => 'delete'
```

and would like to replace it to this

```
:method => :delete
```

in my directory app/views/*.html.erb

How am I be able to achieve this using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that should work in most modern Unix/linux environments (bash, ksh, zsh)

```
find /path/to/app/views -name '*.html.erb' \
| xargs sed -i "/:id => 'delete'/:method => :delete/g"
```

You don't really need to have it on two lines, I just think it makes it a little easier to read.
Note that the last `\` char on line one, MUST be the last char, no trailing spaces or tab chars.

Also, your tags include ruby, I hope, don't want to embed this Linux processing inside ruby, just
run this from the command-line.

Also note that if you're running in OSX, you'll need to use `sed -i"" ...`. AND really old `sed`s don't understand `sed -i`, there are hundreds of posts here that will show you how to deal with that.

As you are working on 100+ files, maybe you want to run just the `find ... *.html.erb'` part to check that the list of files makes sense.

And as you seem to be new to `sed`, better safe that sorry: Copy one of those files to your /tmp dir and make sure the sed cmd does what you need, i.e.

```
sed  "/:id => 'delete'/:method => :delete/g" /tmp/orig.file > /tmp/fixed.file
diff orig.file fixed.file
```

(The redirect into `/tmp/fixed.file` is the basis for solving "no support for `sed -i ..`". )
The `diff` will show you if any unintended changes are creeping in (shouldn't happen).

IHTH.

Comment: what is the  advantage of `| xargs` in place of an `-exec sed -i "/:id => 'delete'/:method => :delete/g" {} \;` ?

Comment: Personally, I find `xargs` easier to read and debug. `xargs` would also allow the O.P. to use `xargs -n1 --maxprocs=20 sed ...` and spawn off `-P(n)` copies if s/he is processing 1000s of files on a multi-processor machine, assuming the local version of `xargs` supports the `--maxprocs=N` option. Good luck to all!